# Get method's arguments?

Tags: php, class, object, methods, arguments

I can check all available methods for an object like so:

```
$methods = get_class_methods($object);
```

But how can I see which arguments have to be sent to these methods?

Is there a function for this?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

You can use [reflection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionmethod.php)...

```
$r = new ReflectionMethod($className, $methodName);
$params = $r->getParameters();
foreach ($params as $param) {
    //$param is an instance of ReflectionParameter
    echo $param->getName();
    echo $param->isOptional();
}
```

Comment: And when you just want to know how many arguments a required, use `getNumberOfRequiredParameters`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionfunctionabstract.getnumberofrequiredparameters.php

Comment: Is there anyway to return what would be accepted as an argument successfully?  For example, if it accepts a string, list the strings that is accepts?

Comment: @GregL: the engine has no concept of "list the strings that it accepts". Specifically, there's no way to tell the engine that it should accept a string in the first place. You can only hint on Arrays, Objects (via class name) and Callbacks (callable hint).

Comment: You could try to parse PHPDoc, it's not easy and your team would have to agree on a format for declaring "accepted strings". Example: http://gonzalo123.com/2011/04/04/reflection-over-phpdoc-with-php/

Comment: If using something like PHPStorm, rather than commenting, you can type-hint the for loop to make it a bit easier to tinker with: `foreach ($params as /** @var \ReflectionParameter */ $param)`

Comment: Just to be 110%...no, 120% clear -- @AngelS.Moreno was being sarcastic.  I won't deny the rare occasion that the information illuminated by reflection is useful, but for 99.999% of industry-worthy code that won't get you crucified in code review meetings, reflection has no place whatsoever.

Comment: I don't remember where my head was 4 years ago, but I like reflection. I don't think I was being sarcastic. However, I agree with @LukeA.Leber I never use reflection in production. I use it for writing tests and command line utils.

Comment: I /am/ needing to use reflection for an MVC framework I'm building in PHP so it does have a place in production, just in very specific instances. It can also be implemented to check your code before accepting it into an versioning repository to implement business-specific rules (no arrays in parameters, for example)