# Check if all parameters for a given function belong to the same class

Tags: php, class, arguments, element

I have a function like this:

```
// merge - merge two or more given trees and returns the resulting tree
function merge() {
    if ($arguments = func_get_args()) {
        $count = func_num_args();

        // and here goes the tricky part... :P
    }
}
```

I can check if all given arguments belong to the same type/class (class, in this case) using functions like `get_class()`, `is_*()` or even `ctype_*()` but that operates (as far as I understand) at the single element level.

What I would ideally like to do is something similar to the `in_array()` function but comparing the class of all elements in the array, so I would do something like `in_class($class, $arguments, true)`.

I could do something like this:

```
$check = true;

foreach ($arguments as $argument) {
    $check &= (get_class($argument) === "Helpers\\Structures\\Tree\\Root" ? true : false);
}

if ($check) {
    // continue with the function execution
}
```

So my question is... is there a defined function for this? Or, at least, a better/more elegant method to accomplish this?

Comment: get_object_vars or get_class_vars maybe? http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php

Comment: What exactly you want to do?

Comment: No, I need to get the class name for each argument and do a check against it. Those two methods will expose each argument properties (`$attributes` in my case) but it won't work :P

Comment: @NullVoid I want to check if all given arguments are instances of the `Tree` class (it's a function for merging trees).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `array_reduce(...)` to apply the function on every element. If your goal is to write a one-liner you could use `create_function(...)` as well.

**Example of array_reduce**

```
<?php
    class foo { }
    class bar { }

    $dataA = array(new foo(), new foo(), new foo());
    $dataB = array(new foo(), new foo(), new bar());

    $resA = array_reduce($dataA, create_function('$a,$b', 'return $a && (get_class($b) === "foo");'), true);
    $resB = array_reduce($dataB, create_function('$a,$b', 'return $a && (get_class($b) === "foo");'), true);

    print($resA ? 'true' : 'false'); // true
    print($resB ? 'true' : 'false'); // false, due to the third element bar.
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387628/php-get-methods-arguments) can fit to your requirement. It has used [ReflectionMethod](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionmethod.php)