# PHP Call function from another function

Tags: php, function

Need to create function that will call other built-in and custom functions, problem is that each called function has different number of parameters.

I supply to a `callerFunction` required function name and required parameters in array, but how do i implement the actual function call?

P.S. I am aware of function scope, this is not a question now.

```
    function myFunction(inputStr, paramOne, paramTwo) {
        echo inputStr . " P1: " . paramOne . " P2: " . paramTwo;
    }
    
    
    function callerFunction(functName, functArgsArr) {
    
        $myVar = "";
        n = 1;
        
        while n <= functArgsArr.length {

            myVar = myVar . " " . functArgsArr[n];

            n++;

        }

        %functName%("Hello World!", %myVar%);
    }

callerFunction("myFunction", ["one", "two"]);
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387628/php-get-methods-arguments

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array

Comment: That code does not look like valid PHP code. What do you want to achieve? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [`call_user_func_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) PHP function:

```php
<?php

function myFunction($inputStr, $paramOne, $paramTwo)
{
    echo $inputStr . " P1: " . $paramOne . " P2: " . $paramTwo;
}

function callerFunction($functionName, array $functArgsArr)
{
    // Prepends 'Hello World' to args array
    array_unshift($functArgsArr, "Hello World");
    
    // Calls $functionName passing the values of $functArgsArray as arguments
    call_user_func_array($functionName, $functArgsArr);
}

callerFunction("myFunction", ["one", "two"]);
```

[Working PHP Fiddle](https://3v4l.org/u7fA9)